# Create new word document with template, change word template path to new server

Tags: sharepoint-online, word

Our old SharePoint 2010 had a special document type "release note", which created a new word document using a specific .dot or .dotx word template:

[image]

Now we moved to SharePoint online (office 365) and a lot of documents were copied. Now when I duplicate an existing release note document or open one, I see that it still loads the template from our old SharePoint 2010 server:

During splash screen of word you suddenly see it pointing to our old SharePoint server to load the template:
[image: W]

Hope the question was clear, as I don't know how this was configured in SharePoint 2010, nor how to modify this in SharePoint Office 365..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using only one content type in the library, then go to:
Library settings -> Advanced settings -> Template URL

Otherwise you have to set the template on the content type:
Library settings -> choose the content type -> Advanced Settings -> template URL

Comment: The old SharePoint 2010 has a content type of "release notes" but the new one doesn't have this specific type of word document to quickly create using a dot template.

Comment: have you checked the template associated with your content type?  Maybe you need to attach something new or edit the existing one, it might help to correct the issue

Comment: first had to go to site settings to setup the custom content type, next associate it with the library settings.

and before all this in the SharePoint admin center allowing custom scripts to upload my template ( https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint/cannot-upload-document-template-to-content-type/f3b27abb-52d0-41e5-be45-dc5185ba3f0e )

Answer (score 1):

Go in Document Library settings, click on the content type.  Try changing the template to something else (a blank Word doc perhaps?).  Then test it.

If that doesn't help, try reverting it back to the 'Use the default'.

BTW - I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm using SP2013.

[image: Content Type]

Comment: before you can upload a new template you have to enable custom scripts in SharePoint admin center ( https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint/cannot-upload-document-template-to-content-type/f3b27abb-52d0-41e5-be45-dc5185ba3f0e )